# Trouble importing Compass Extensions

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am using [rgbapng](https://github.com/aaronrussell/compass-rgbapng/commit/71c2072a792f0d3db173e34002e29b3eaf04c4ec) on my sass project with compass to generate transparent backgrounds cross-browser but I cant seem to get it to be included. It have included the line `@import "rgbapng";` but I get this error:

```
error sass/wireframes.scss (Line 103 of sass/_base.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: rgbapng.
Load paths:
  /Users/fredparke/sites/sandbox/sites/all/themes/sandbox/sass
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  /Users/fredparke/sites/sandbox/sites/all/themes/sandbox/sass-extensions/zen-grids/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just missing the `require 'rgbapng'` in my config.rb file. I did try this first thing to no effect but you have to **close and reopen your terminal window** for the change to take effect.

Comment: You shouldn't have to close/reopen, just restart your `compass watch`.