# Compass loads wrong paths for plugins like the gem compass-rgbapng

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I tried to setup my project as normal. In the config.rb file i require rgbapng and before of corse I installed it with `sudo gem install compass-rgbapng`.

Now when I now run `compass compile .` I get the following Errors.

```
compass compile .
    error sass/styles.sass (Line 5: File to import not found or unreadable: rgbapng.
Load paths:
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /home/my_user/public_html/spinnwerk/my_project/public/sass
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets)
```

The gem `compass-rgbapng` is located under `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1`. So How do I tell compass to watch in the right directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble importing Compass Extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746131/trouble-importing-compass-extensions)

Comment: nope, like I wrote, I am including rgbapng in my project.

Comment: damn it! The config.rb was in the wrong location, so no require "rgbapng". I'm so sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I fixe it for me by copying the file to te compass-core folder.

```
sudo cp /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1/lib/stylesheets/_rgbapng.scss /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
```

This is a bad fix in my opinion, so I am still looking for a better way. If you can find one, pleas let me know.